# add items to listview and filter existing item

Tags: c#, winforms, list, listview

I'm making a program that calculates the grade of the student and see if the student is an honor student. The problem is that only the list for the 1st honor students is added. the rest who belongs to the 2nd and 3rd are no longer displayed. I've been trying to figure this out for almost 2 days now and I still cant still find a way to solve this.

```
List<int> clsid = new List<int>(){2,3,5};
int g = clsid.Count();
List<int> temp_rank1 = new List<int>();
List<int> temp_rank2 = new List<int>();
List<int> temp_rank3 = new List<int>();
//get the student id
foreach (int fr in clsid)
{
 conek.OPEN("select stud_id from class_info where class_id = '"+fr+"' and tmp_gr1 >= 88");
 while (conek.reader.Read())
  {
   temp_rank1.Add(conek.reader.GetInt32(0));
  }
  conek.CLOSE();
 conek.OPEN("select stud_id from class_info where class_id = '" + fr + "' and tmp_gr1 >=85");
 while (conek.reader.Read())
 {
 temp_rank2.Add(conek.reader.GetInt32(0));
 }
 conek.CLOSE();
 conek.OPEN("select stud_id from class_info where class_id = '" + fr + "' and tmp_gr1 >= 83 ");
 while (conek.reader.Read())
 {
  temp_rank3.Add(conek.reader.GetInt32(0));
 }
 conek.CLOSE();
}
```

get the student id if the total number of the same student_id is equal to the total number of subjects which is g.

```
var tmp1 = temp_rank1.GroupBy(n => n).Where(n => n.Count() == g).Select(n => n.Key);
 if (tmp1.Count() >= 1)
   {
    foreach (var gh in tmp1)
    {
    rank1.Add(gh);
    }
   }
var tmp2 = temp_rank2.GroupBy(n => n).Where(n => n.Count() == g).Select(n => n.Key);
 if (tmp2.Count() >= 1)
    {
     foreach (var gh in tmp2)
     {
      rank2.Add(gh);
     }
    }
var tmp3 = temp_rank3.GroupBy(n => n).Where(n => n.Count() == g).Select(n => n.Key);
 if (tmp3.Count() >= 1)
    {
     foreach (var gh in tmp3)
     {
      rank3.Add(gh);
     }
    }
```

for the first honor students

```
nye.SubItems.Add("First Honor");
listView1.Items.Add(nye);
int yt = 0;
foreach (int fgd in idr1)
{
if(rcs1[yt] >= 90){
ListViewItem gtb = new ListViewItem();
conek.OPEN("select concat(l_name,', ',f_name,' ',ucase(substring(m_name,1,1)),'.') from students where stud_id = '"+fgd+"' ");
while (conek.reader.Read())
 {
  gtb.SubItems.Add(conek.reader.GetString(0));
 }
 conek.CLOSE();
 foreach (int gfad in clsid)
  {
   conek.OPEN("select tmp_gr1 from class_info where class_info.stud_id = '" + fgd + "' and class_id = '" + gfad + "' ");
   while (conek.reader.Read())
   {                        
   gtb.SubItems.Add(Math.Round(conek.reader.GetDouble(0),2).ToString());
   }
   conek.CLOSE();
  }
  gtb.SubItems.Add(Math.Round(rcs1[yt],2).ToString());
  yt++;
  listView1.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[] { gtb });
 }
}
```

for the second honor students

```
listView1.Items.Add("");
ListViewItem nyek = new ListViewItem();
nyek.SubItems.Add("Second Honor");
listView1.Items.Add(nyek);
int yet = 0;
foreach (int fed in idr2)
{
if(!idr1.Contains(fed))
{
 if (rcs2[yet] >= 88)
 {
  ListViewItem gtbs = new ListViewItem();
  conek.OPEN("select concat(l_name,', ',f_name,' ',ucase(substring(m_name,1,1)),'.') from students where stud_id ='" + fed + "'");
  while (conek.reader.Read())
  {
  gtbs.SubItems.Add(conek.reader.GetString(0));
  }
  conek.CLOSE();
   foreach (int gfa in clsid)
   {
   conek.OPEN("select tmp_gr1 from class_info left join students on class_info.stud_id = students.stud_id where class_info.stud_id = '" + fed + "' and class_id = '" + gfa + "' ");
   while (conek.reader.Read())
   {
    gtbs.SubItems.Add(Math.Round(conek.reader.GetDouble(0), 2).ToString());
   }
  conek.CLOSE();
 }
 gtbs.SubItems.Add(Math.Round(rcs2[yet], 2).ToString());
 yet++;
 listView1.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[] { gtbs });
  }
 }
}
```

for third honor students

```
listView1.Items.Add("");
ListViewItem ne = new ListViewItem();
ne.SubItems.Add("Third Honor");
listView1.Items.Add(ne);
int yat = 0;
foreach (int fbv in idr3)
{
if (!idr2.Contains(fbv))
 {
  if (rcs3[yat] >= 85)
  {
  ListViewItem bnb = new ListViewItem();
  conek.OPEN("select concat(l_name,', ',f_name,' ',ucase(substring(m_name,1,1)),'.') from students where stud_id = '" + fbv + "' ");
  while (conek.reader.Read())
  {
  bnb.SubItems.Add(conek.reader.GetString(0));
  }
  conek.CLOSE();
  foreach (int nmj in clsid)
  {
   conek.OPEN("select tmp_gr1 from class_info left join students on class_info.stud_id = students.stud_id where class_info.stud_id = '" + fbv + "' and class_id = '" + nmj + "' ");
   while (conek.reader.Read())
   {
   bnb.SubItems.Add(Math.Round(conek.reader.GetDouble(0), 2).ToString());
   }
  conek.CLOSE();
  }
 bnb.SubItems.Add(Math.Round(rcs3[yat], 2).ToString());
 yat++;
 listView1.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[] { bnb });
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that inside that foreach loops you are iterating only tmp1:

```
var tmp1 =    temp_rank1.GroupBy(n => n).Where(n => n.Count() == g).Select(n => n.Key);
if (tmp1.Count() >= 1)
 {
  foreach (var gh in tmp1)
  {
  rank1.Add(gh);
  }
 }
var tmp2 = temp_rank2.GroupBy(n => n).Where(n => n.Count() == g).Select(n => n.Key);
if (tmp2.Count() >= 1)
  {
   foreach (var gh in tmp1)
   {
    rank2.Add(gh);
   }
  }
var tmp3 = temp_rank3.GroupBy(n => n).Where(n => n.Count() == g).Select(n => n.Key);
if (tmp3.Count() >= 1)
  {
   foreach (var gh in tmp1)
   {
    rank3.Add(gh);
   }
}
```

Anyway i would suggest you to refactor because this code is barely readable and maintainable.
Extract methods for similar code, use linq's .Any() instead of .Count >=1 and use .AddRange instead of iterating and using .Add

Actually you are doing the same mistake in more place, like in the second honor part it is:

```
listView1.Items.Add("");
ListViewItem nyek = new ListViewItem();
nyek.SubItems.Add("Second Honor");
listView1.Items.Add(nyek);
int yet = 0;
foreach (int fed in idr2)
{
if(!idr1.Contains(fed))
{
 if (rcs2[yet] >= 88)
 {
  ListViewItem gtbs = new ListViewItem();
  conek.OPEN("select concat(l_name,', ',f_name,' ',ucase(substring(m_name,1,1)),'.')     from students where stud_id ='" + fed + "'");
  while (conek.reader.Read())
  {
  gtbs.SubItems.Add(conek.reader.GetString(0));
  }
  conek.CLOSE();
   foreach (int gfa in clsid)
   {
   conek.OPEN("select tmp_gr1 from class_info left join students on class_info.stud_id     = students.stud_id where class_info.stud_id = '" + fed + "' and class_id = '" + gfa + "'     ");
   while (conek.reader.Read())
   {
    gtbs.SubItems.Add(Math.Round(conek.reader.GetDouble(0), 2).ToString());
   }
  conek.CLOSE();
 }
 gtbs.SubItems.Add(Math.Round(rcs2[yet], 2).ToString());
 yet++;
 listView1.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[] { gtbs });
  }
 }
}
```

when it should be:

```
listView2.Items.Add("");
ListViewItem nyek = new ListViewItem();
nyek.SubItems.Add("Second Honor");
listView1.Items.Add(nyek);
int yet = 0;
foreach (int fed in idr2)
{
if(!idr2.Contains(fed))
{
 if (rcs2[yet] >= 88)
 {
  ListViewItem gtbs = new ListViewItem();
  conek.OPEN("select concat(l_name,', ',f_name,' ',ucase(substring(m_name,1,1)),'.')     from students where stud_id ='" + fed + "'");
  while (conek.reader.Read())
  {
  gtbs.SubItems.Add(conek.reader.GetString(0));
  }
  conek.CLOSE();
   foreach (int gfa in clsid)
   {
   conek.OPEN("select tmp_gr1 from class_info left join students on class_info.stud_id     = students.stud_id where class_info.stud_id = '" + fed + "' and class_id = '" + gfa + "'     ");
   while (conek.reader.Read())
   {
    gtbs.SubItems.Add(Math.Round(conek.reader.GetDouble(0), 2).ToString());
   }
  conek.CLOSE();
 }
 gtbs.SubItems.Add(Math.Round(rcs2[yet], 2).ToString());
 yet++;
 listView2.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[] { gtbs });
  }
 }
}
```

The same thing for the 3rd one... just look carefully where you are referring to the first list when the second should be referred.

Comment: thank you for pointing that out. i would like to change the codes as much as i would like to but i'm running out of time. i just need to make this program run without errors. I changed the values in the foreach loop but still get the same answer can u please help me out a bit more

Comment: Edited, please try that.

Comment: i was actually referring to the id list in idr1. i used that to filter the ids. if the id in ird2 exists in idr1 i dont have to add that one. same goes for the third honor

Comment: look at the last line, thats the listview you are trying to fill right? it was listView1 instead of listView2, in no other place you are referring to listView2.

Comment: no.. im trying to fill out all the items in a single listview.

Comment: Ok... why is the comparison `if (rcs2[yet] >= 88)` before filling the list when in the query it is `select stud_id from class_info where class_id = '" + fr + "' and tmp_gr1 >=85`? same for the other ranks, the comparison is with different values.

Comment: i forgot to include this. rcs2[yet] is a list of the average grade. the index of the ids and the rcs2 are the same.

Comment: i forgot to include this. rcs2[yet] is a list of the average grade. the index of the ids and the rcs2 are the same.
so the entry is being filtered by two conditions. in the first honor, only one condition is needed which is the rcs1[x] >= 90. in the second honor and third honor, the two conditions is then applied. if the ID does not exist in the id1 and the average is >=88 then add to second honor list. if the ID does not exist in the id2 and the average is >=85 then add to third honor list.